# iOS9: Try to open app via scheme if possible, or redirect to app store otherwise

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, safari, ios9

My question is about **iOS9 only!**

I have an `HTML` landing page, and I try to redirect the user **to my app** via URL scheme if the app is installed, or redirect to the **Appstore** otherwise.

My code is:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  body.onclick = function () {
    openApp();
  };
});

var timeout;

function preventPopup() {

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;
    window.removeEventListener('pagehide', preventPopup);
}

function openApp(appInstanceId, platform) {

  window.addEventListener('pagehide', preventPopup);
  document.addEventListener('pagehide', preventPopup);

  // create iframe
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
  iframe.src = 'myscheme://launch?var=val';

  var timeoutTime = 1000;
  timeout = setTimeout(function () {

    document.location = 'https://itunes.apple.com/app/my-app';

  }, timeoutTime);
}
```

The problem is that the `iframe` trick doesn't work in `Safari` `iOS9`.

Any idea why?

My `iframe` trick based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701708/how-to-prevent-ios-safari-alert-when-trying-to-open-non-installed-native-app/25054876#25054876) answer.

Comment: the **openApp** redirect to safari or not

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik What do u mean?

Comment: sorry , in your condition redirect to safari or not

Comment: But I want to switch app if possible (and don't show any alert if it's impossible) or redirect to app store. I don't want to redirect any way..

Comment: friend , I don't know javascript, but I worked on URL schema on more than three apps in iOS, I surely support you to find the solution ,

Comment: Friend, Thanks for your help, and same thanks to your support. I asked about `JavaScript`+`Safari`+`iOS`+`URLScheme` not only about `iOS` and not only about `URLScheme`

Comment: @gran33 have you tested it removing `display:none`? Maybe Safari on iOS9 doesn't open url/iframe not displayed...

Comment: @LuigiSaggese Yes, same problem :/

Comment: @gran33 i have same issue! Some websites made it with 2-3 redirect (i.e. LinkedIn). I don't like st.derrick solution, but maybe replacing redirect to store with a redirect to another, or same page skipping uri-scheme launch, could be a solution. What do you think?

Comment: @LuigiSaggese I think we can't run away from the big brother (He'll keep watching us..), and we must use `Universal Links` by Apple

Answer (score 23):

The iframe trick no longer works -- my guess is that Apple knows it will encourage more developers to implement Universal Links, more quickly.

You can still set `window.location='your-uri-scheme://';` and fallback to the App Store after 500ms. There is a "dance" between popups if you take this approach, as we do at [Branch](https://branch.io) (we do as a fallback if Universal Links don't work).

```
window.location = 'your-uri-scheme://'; // will result in error message if app not installed
setTimeout(function() {
   // Link to the App Store should go here -- only fires if deep link fails                
   window.location = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myapp/id123456789?ls=1&mt=8";
}, 500);
```

I wish I had a better answer for you. iOS 9 is definitely more limited.

For a helpful overview of what's needed for Universal Links should you go that route, check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891777/ios-9-safari-iframe-src-with-custom-url-scheme-not-working/32708258#32708258) or [read this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/128948/universal-links-make-connection)

Comment: @formatjam yes, if the app is not installed. It's unfortunate.

Comment: When the location change and the fallback timer are invoked from a user interaction event (e.g. an onclick handler on a button), as opposed to running e.g. onload, the location change in the timer always executes and the user always ends up being bumped to the app store. It looks like in this interactive scenario, the "Open this page in 'appname'" popup dialog that gets shown as a result of the first window.location assignment doesn't prevent further location changes from happening. Also, it appears the timeout can be as low as 1ms, I didn't see any diff between 500 and 1, Chrome included.

Comment: Further to my comment above, to ensure the flow works as expected even in the interactive scenario, you will need to 'create indirection' by wrapping the entire thing (i.e. incl. the first window.location assignment) in another timeout. E.g.:  setTimeout(function () {window.location = 'your-uri-scheme://'; setTimeout(function () { window.location = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myapp/id123456789?ls=1&mt=8' }, 1); }, 1);

Comment: @obiuquido144 I don't see how wrapping it in another timeout help. Im my case it didn't.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me - it will show the "Open in app myapp?" dialog for a second and then it will redirect to my fallback url in the setTimeout method. Any idea as to why?

Comment: Has anyone figured this out?

Comment: @tommy.bonderenka Looks like a 9.2 thing where the "Open this page" dialog is no longer modal, so the redirect is not prevented.

Comment: on iOS versions >12.3, after opening the App from Safari it redirects to App Store in a split second.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned setting `window.location` on iOS 9 still works. However, this brings up an Open in App dialog. I've put an example on https://bartt.me/openapp that:

1. Launches Twitter when the *Open in Twitter app* is clicked.
2. Falls back to the Twitter app in the App Store.
3. Redirects to Twitter or the App Store *without* the user selecting *Open* in the *Open in App* dialog.
4. Works in all browsers on iOS and Android.

Look at the source of https://lab.bartt.me/openapp for more information.

Comment: It does again, was temporarily turned off.

Comment: Re point 3, I tested in iOS 9.3.5, and it doesn't appear to be able to open Twitter without the user clicking open in the "Open" button in the "Open this page in 'Twitter'" dialog.

Comment: +1 Does it work in iOS 9 without the "Open in app" dialog? Thanks for sharing. May you please add your code to the post to be in compliance with Stack Overflow rules.

Comment: @BartTeeuwisse can you please provide the code? The linked page results in a 404. Thanks!

Comment: @der_gluateng I've updated the link to the source code.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in the iOS Safari browser (anymore?). When user doesn't have Twitter installed on iOS 13 and taps the button, you get the generic 'Safari cannot open this page because it's invalid' alert.

Answer (score 3):

Answering this since it's 2023 now and some changes have happened. This [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32774701/1195352) is generally correct however there is a major issue: the app store will still open even if does successfully open the app.

The way to get around this is to detect when the first popup happens by monitoring the window `blur` event. If the blur occurs then don't perform the fallback because the user has successfully opened the app. But if the app is focused then perform the app store fallback.

You also need to use the hidden app store deep link `itms-appss://...`.

```js
var isBlurred = false;
var didFallback = false;

window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  isBlurred = true;
});

window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  isBlurred = false;
  appStoreFallback();
});

function appStoreFallback() {
  if (isBlurred || didFallback) return;

  // Since we are using the native deep link, we wrap it in a custom
  // confirm prompt to prevent it from opening immediately.
  if (window.confirm(`Open in "App Store"?`)) {
    window.top.location = "itms-appss://apps.apple.com/app/idYOUR_ID_HERE";
  }
  
  didFallback = true;
}

window.top.location = 'your-uri-scheme://'; 
setTimeout(function() {
  appStoreFallback();
}, 500);
```

As an aside, this is basically what Branch.io does under the hood and wanted to share. I've used them for a couple of years but now but stopped since their URLs get marked by spam filters and their costs are high if your app has any moderate amount of usage.

Comment: Thanks! the solution works fine also for Android and Windows PWA. As a simple alternative you could also use `clearTimeout` in the blur event callback.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try giving you app support to Universal Links

Idea:
Avoid custom (JavaScript, iframe) solutions in Safari, replace you code with a supported Universal Link.

Example

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
    <div class"app-banner-style">
        <a href="http://yourdomain.com">In app open</a> 
    </div>
...content
</body>
</html>
```

if you app support Universal Links (e.g. yourdomain.com), you muss configure your domain (and path) and iOS9 should be react to it link opening you App. **That is only theory**, but I guess should be work :)

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12

Comment: @carlos.baeza that is a good way to approach to problem, but question refer to `javascript`, `iframe`, `Safari`

Comment: This should be the correct answer @carlos.baeza ... the only problem is the universal links binding is way too complex. But you were right. I up-scored you.

Comment: but it does not open appstore if the app is not installed

Answer (score 0):

iframe hack doesn't work in ios9 anymore. Possible solution is use two buttons.
Example:

```
$('#goToStoreBtn').text( "go to store" ).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    window.location = storeUrl; // https://itunes.apple.com/...
});

$('#goToAppBtn').text( "go to app" ).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    window.location = appUrl;  // myApp://...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is relatively old thread, but I have created a library that supports deeplinking on most of the modern mobile browsers. But this requires separate deeplinking page which needs to be hosted in different domain to support universal linking in ios9 facebook browser.

https://github.com/prabeengiri/DeepLinkingToNativeApp