# open app with custom scheme - prevent "open in <appname>" warning?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, safari

I want to open my app from safari. This is the custom scheme in the info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.appvendor.rentalapp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>open-rental</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

If I press a button in safari like this:

```
<a href="open-rental://custom-string">Open App</a>
```

I get an iOS Warning `"Open in <app-name>"`. My question is can I prevent this warning popup?

Comment: I don't believe there's any way around it.  It's part of the increased security in iOS 9.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? Can we use universal links ?

Answer (score 0):

[another item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689483/ios9-try-to-open-app-via-scheme-if-possible-or-redirect-to-app-store-otherwise)
I think this can help u

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location = "weixin://";  //scheme
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location = appstore url;
    }, 500);
}, 1);
```

Comment: You explain more about your answer.[From review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10520279)