# How to add http link as Url Schemes in iOS Swift3

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I need to set a web url `(http://xxxx.com/project/test`) in Url scheme, so if the app is not installed then I have to redirect to the Safari Web page or else need to open app directly. As this Web Url is relate to my App website.

I tried setting scheme without http/https and can open the app successfully from browser. Is it possible to add `Host` in Url scheme like Android?

This can be possible using `Universal Links`, but I want to know is there any other way to achieve this to support iOS 8? Please suggest me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set a Javascript redirect once the page loads in Safari and attempt to open the app. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689483/ios9-try-to-open-app-via-scheme-if-possible-or-redirect-to-app-store-otherwise)