# Opening installed app using URL Scheme is not working

Tags: swift2, ios9, url-scheme

I have an app which shares a link. When someone taps on that link, it is opening `Safari` mobile app, then automatically opens app (lets say :  AppName) if is installed on his device.

```
let url =  "appname://listener?mid=560aa7"
```

This is working perfect on iOS 8+, but on iOS 9 stopped to work.
Please note that I have FB added also, on `URL Scheme`.
My `URLType` is like this:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
          <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
          <string>com.appname.mobile</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb705.....</string>
            <string>appname</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

And starting with iOS9, I added:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>appname</string>
</array>
```

And no success. Can anyone help me?

I tried with `appname:`  or  `appname://`  and no success.

Also I aded new mothod for `openURL`:

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool
```

Comment: I am succesful only if typing just the URL scheme "foo.bar.app://". Once I try to include anything behind the slashes (//), Safari tells that address of the page is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem on your side, seems like everything is set correctly.
However, regarding iOS 9, other users reported this problem with iframe. Make sure the things are setup correctly on server side. Check these 2 links:

[iOS 9 iFrame Problem 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689483/ios9-try-to-open-app-via-scheme-if-possible-or-redirect-to-app-store-otherwise?lq=1)

[iOS 9 iFrame Problem 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891777/ios-9-safari-iframe-src-with-custom-url-scheme-not-working)

Comment: How should this relate with a server? Did you noticed we are using custom URL schemes, e.g. foo.bar.app://open meaning there might be domain that does not exist at all? So, there's no server that could be tweaked in any way!